# yield/return from python generators

Tags: python, yield

Bumped into a behaviour I'm struggling to grasp without an assistance. Here's a recursive function:

```
OPERATORS = ['+', '-', '*', '/']

def recursive(value, operands):
    if not operands:
        return value
    for operator in OPERATORS:
        new_value = str(eval(value + operator + operands[-1]))
        new_operands = operands[:-1]
        yield from recursive(new_value, new_operands)

def countdown(value, operands):
    return next(i for i in recursive(value, operands) if i == '0')

ans = countdown('5', ['1', '2', '3'])
print(ans)
```

`return value` raises `StopIteration` which is not handled by caller so exception is raised before anything returns.

If `return value` is substituted by `yield value; return` like this:

```
def recursive(value, operands):
    if not operands:
        yield value
        return
    for operator in OPERATORS:
        new_value = str(eval(value + operator + operands[-1]))
        new_operands = operands[:-1]
        yield from recursive(new_value, new_operands)
```

or `yield value; raise StopIteration` or `yield value; raise StopIteration(value)` or loop is hidden under `else` clause then exception is handled by caller the way I expect and function eventually returns `'0'`. All of these also raise exception: `raise StopIteration`, both bare and with argument, `yield; return value`, and bare `return`.

In short, caller breaks when `StopIteration` is raised and `yield` never returned.

Why?

[PEP380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#id13) states that first `StopIteration` is handled in a different way then others. [PEP479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479) says:

> Currently, StopIteration raised accidentally inside a generator function will be interpreted as the end of the iteration by the loop construct driving the generator.

Apparently, except the first time. Still, the details of underlying implementation and exact reasoning behind it are unclear to me.

Two more additional questions:

- what's the right way of writing this snippet? [return (yield value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184576/when-to-use-return-yield-something)?
- is it a quirk, a feature, or something else?

**Edit:** fixed mistakes in code

**Edit2:** As far as I understand the execution flow in the first snippet is following:

1. `countdown` creates generator from `recursive('5', ['1', '2', '3'])`
2. Which spawns generators all the way down the tree to `recursive('11', [])`
3. At this point `StopIteration('11')` is raised

And here is the tricky part. What happens here? How `StopIteration` is handled?

Second snippet:

1. same
2. same
3. `'11'` is yielded upwards until it reaches countdown
4. Where it gets rejected by `if '11' == '0'`
5. Control flow reaches back to `yield '11'` and raises `StopIteration`
6. Repeat until `'0'`

From what I see now that is pretty much expected behaviour. `StopIteration` is intrecepted by it's caller and does not propagate upward. Caller in turn raises `StopIteration` without arguments. That is why the `'11'` part of an original exception never reached `countdown`. Exception in the first snippet traceback was bare `StopIteration` raised in `countdown` by `recursive('5', ['1', '2', '3']`.

Comment: Could you explain what you *want* this code to do?

Comment: @scott-hunter It was a part of this problem
https://np.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/6fe9cv/20170605_challenge_318_easy_countdown_game_show/, I've simplified it for a sake of readability. Right now I'm just interested why straight `return value` fails and what's the reasoning behind the more complicated solution.

Comment: I believe that your confusion stems from not understanding how a generator works.  `return` causes an unnatural termination to the generator, raising an exception.  In general, `return` should *not* appear in a generator.

Comment: @prune my question is exactly about the details of that unnatural termination. What happens under the hood? `return value` transforms to `StopIteration(value)`, fine, but what happens next? Why `StopIteration` is intercepted by a caller if `yield` already returned and is not intercepted otherwise?
Thanks for a general advise, I guess I'll stick with it.

Comment: When I run your code, I don't get that trace.  Rather, I get an invalid `+` operation between `int` and `str`, because you return an integer where your processing requires a string.  Most of all, I'm not at all clear about where you *want* a function vs a generator.

Comment: @prune fixed errors in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StopIteration` is raised when you finally run out of operands. Until then, you continue to recur on your list, evaluating results and shortening the list. I think that the yield has returned, but it returned to its caller, which was the previous invocation of `recursive`, rather than `countdown`.

In the second example, you yield a value, and the ensuing call to `recursive` is what raises `StopIteration`, as it immediately hits a return.

As for the example `return (yield 42)`, yes, this is a quirk.  The poster of that question was stumbling through making a generator, and discovered that code he later thought was wrong, had actually returned something.